# Find path of a nested or non-nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, routes

Working in Rails 3.2, I a polymorphic Subscription model whose subscribable_type may or may not be a nested resource. I'm trying to display the full URL link in an email view, but have no knowledge whether or not that resource is nested.

When I try `url_for @model` on a nested resource, it fails, expecting `url_for [@parent, @model]`. Unfortunately, I do not know how to discover the parent as defined in the Routes table.

Is there a way to identify the route path for a nested resource? If I could match the model to a route, I could fill in the necessary IDs.

As of right now, I've defined a method in my models called `parent_resource :model` that can be traversed, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Within my `routes.draw`:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :topics do
      resources :comments
    end
  end

  resources :subscriptions
```

(I realize I shouldn't be nesting so deeply)

**Edit: Additional Information**

My Subscription model is a resource I use to manage notifications. Subscribable types are provided a link that toggles the subscription for that user on that subscribable_type / subscribable_id on or off.

I then go through a `Notifier < ActionMailer::Base` which is provided the Subscription instance, and mail the user.

Through that setup, I'm trying to get the full url of `subscription.subscribable` which may be a Topic or a Project.

I realize that I could hammer out the conditions in this small case through a helper method, but I am curious to know how one would approach this if there were dozens of nested model pairs.

Comment: Could you also add relevant section from your routes file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way to accomplish what I'm doing, but this works for me right now.

This builds a nested resource array off the shortest valid route helper and generates a URL:

(Tested in `rails console`)

```
resource = Comment.first
resource_name = resource.class.to_s.downcase 

helper = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers.grep(/.*#{resource_name}_path$/).first.to_s.split('_')
built = helper.slice!(-2,2) # Shortest possible valid helper, "comment_path"

while !(app.respond_to?(built.join("_").to_sym)) 
  built.unshift helper.pop
end

built.pop # Get rid of "path"
resources = built.reverse.reduce([]) { |memo, name| 
  if name == resource_name
    memo << resource
  else
    memo <<  memo.last.send(name.to_sym) # comment.topic, or topic.project (depends on belongs_to)
  end
}
resources.reverse!

app.polymorphic_url(resources) # "http://www.example.com/projects/1/topics/1/comments/1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention subscription but your routes are completely different. I'm guessing the routes you gave were just an example then. I would start with trying to get rid of the custom parent_resource method you created. You can probably do the same thing simpler with adding a belongs_to through and maybe with conditions if you need too:

```
belongs_to :projects, :through => :topics, :conditions => ['whatever your conditions are']
```

I'd have one of those per parent type so I can do things like:

```
object.project.present?
```

And from there I could easily know if its nested or not and simplify things by letting rails do the parent traversal. That ought to simplify things enough to where you can at least figure out what type of subscription you have pretty easily. Next, I'd probably add some matched routes or try to cram an :as => 'somename' into my routes so I can call them directly after determining the nested part. One option would be something like this:

```
match "projects/subscription/:id" => "projects#subscription", :as => :project_subscription
match "other/subscription/:id" => "other#subscription", :as => :other_subscription
```

And so its pretty obvious to see how you can just specify which url you want now with something like:

```
if @object.project.present? 
  project_subscription_path(@object)
else
  other_subscription_path(@object)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've clarified my question further. I'm looking more to know how to generally find the parent, instead of explicitly naming the parent's class name, i.e. `@object.project`.

Comment: I understand that the routing system can route multiple paths to a single controller, so I see why there's no direct way to do this. However, I still wonder if there's a way to identify routes by names within ActionDispatch::Route and the build off that? Or is that making things more complicated than need be?